# Python Pygame OSx error relating to El Capitan System

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I'm installing PyGame on to OSx ElCapitan with a System install of 2.7 and Brew install of Python3 following [this blog post](http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x/).  The brew install Python3 worked fine with

```
sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

But

```
sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

runs into the following error

```
running install_headers
creating /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pygame


error: could not create '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pygame': Operation not permitted


Rolling back uninstall of pygame
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip-wepMKN-build/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-sWpHWA-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-wepMKN-build
```

which I believe is related to the new [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) in El Capitan.  Everything was updated and doctored before so the system is running well otherwise.

Any help on how I can overcome this would be awesome and helpful to many I'm sure.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Maybe have a look [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-el-capitan-max-os-x-upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arthur has provided a link to a thread on the possible solutions to this problem although I'm not sure I'm ready to turn off the SIP so personally would opt for the user only install suggested by a not approved answer on the aforementioned thread.